# Using 42 foot pipe sections to make 45 degree bend

Tags: geometry

I was asked a question today regarding the number of 42 foot joints of steel pipe needed to make a 45 degree curve.  I was told that each joint of pipe could only be bent at a maximum of 2 degrees.  Can anyone provide me a formula to make this calculation in the future.?

Comment: Like $$\left\lceil\frac{45}{2}\right\rceil = 23 ?$$

Comment: Great.  Thank you so much for your help.  That was the formula I used but wanted to make sure I was correct.